Problems with AIC values in GAMMs
To test a hypothesis I am using generalised additive mixed models in R, and built the model below with mgcv package:
    gam(Resp ~ s(Pred1, bs="cr") + s(Pred2, bs="cr") + s(Pred3, bs="cr") + s(Pred4, bs="cr") + ti(Pred3, Pred4) + s(Factor, bs="re"), data=Data, family=binomial)

Then, I used the dredge function (MuMIn package) to obtain a list of all potential models ordered by increasing AIC value. In this list the first four models have the same AIC value, and thus, same DeltaAIC and AIC weights (see image below). And this keeps happening with the following models.
Why is this happening? Is it an issue estimating Pred1 and the interaction between Pred3 and Pred4? Any help will be appreciated!


Your model selection makes no sense and you should just ignore that output.
You have a tensor product pure interaction smooth that is included in some models when one of the marginal smooths is not present as a main effect.
This approach is terrible from a hypothesis testing point of view. Why use a criterion (AIC) that minimises cross validated (leave one out) predictive fit?
Why should terms either be included or exclude from a model, though you don't know which, yet you do know that the effects if included are smooth?
I would suggest doing one of two things:

just fit your model and, assuming you don't have too much of a concurvity problem, use the estimated effects from that model to test your hypotheses, or
use additional penalties on the null spaces of all of the smooths by adding select = TRUE, or use specialist shrinkage smooths (add bs = "cs" or bs = "ts" to those smooths you want subject to selection) to just have a modified penalty that can apply a selection effect to a chosen set of smooths.

The benefit of 1. is that, assuming you came to the full model with your predictors without looking at the data, you can trust the p values and credible intervals to have approximate correctness or coverage, and you can focus on the estimated effect sizes from a scientific viewpoint rather than in terms of statistical significance.
The benefit of 2. is that you can do feature selection if you must but you do it in a principled way that still allows for reasonable inference (p values and credible intervals are still reasonably OK) unlike your torturing the data with dredge(). I really wish that thing wasn't used so prominently and that AIC was less used than it is (it has its place but what you are doing for hypothesis testing is not it).
